# Add .Net core 2.0 to Web Application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webforms, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to include **.NET Core 2.0** to a existent project build with **.NET Web Application**, without the need to create an new **.Net Core 2.0** and migrate everything from the **old project** to the **new one**.

I was able to add **Web API** to the old project and add an extra configuration to the global.asax to make the route work.

So I was wondering if would be possible to use the **.Net Core 2.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to create a new project and move your functionality over.

Comment: Damm, I was hopping that was something... Thanks for the reply. Looks like I'll need to move start moving things.